GCP PromQL smooth charts/expected value
I would like to smooth the charts so that any spike/drop will be ignored, which can computes the expected value for me.
An example charts would be rate(Metrics[1m])
I've tried applying an longer rolling window, for example:
rate(Metrics[1h])
However, such charts gets unexpected spike very often in GCP, which might due to the behavior of rate() in PromQL.
Is there any other way to smooth the charts, or computes the expected values of rate(metrics[1m])

Therate(m[d]) function calculates the average increase rate for the metric m over the given interval d, which ends at the displayed point's timestamp. So, the correct way to smooth the calculated increase rate is to increase the duration d in square brackets.
If you see unexpected spikes on the graph when increasing d, then this may be related to some bug in GCP implementation of Prometheus.
